# Jquery validation for confirm password

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using Jquery for form validation , in that I have password and confirm password fields like this,

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="cfmPassword" id="cfmPassword" >
```

Here other fields are working fine but not confirm password field,
The rule for `cfmPassword` is as follow ,

```
password: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 6,
    maxlength: 10

},
cfmPassword: {
    required: true,
    equalTo: "#password",
    minlength: 6,
    maxlength: 10
}
```

but here the problem is if `cfmpassword` is not same as `password` also it doesnt show error message. please any one help me in this.

Comment: You have not shown enough code to reproduce the issue.  I make this claim because the accepted answer below contains the same code as your OP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BSdc8/2/)

```
<form id="formCheckPassword">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"/>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cfmPassword" id="cfmPassword" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
 </form>



 $("#formCheckPassword").validate({
           rules: {
               password: { 
                 required: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    maxlength: 10,

               } , 

                   cfmPassword: { 
                    equalTo: "#password",
                     minlength: 6,
                     maxlength: 10
               }


           },
     messages:{
         password: { 
                 required:"the password is required"

               }
     }

});
```

Comment: Your code is the same as the OP's so I guess I don't understand the original problem.

Comment: There was some sintax error.. Maybe the question has been updated

Comment: BTW, you only need the `equalTo` rule on the second field:  http://jsfiddle.net/BSdc8/3/

Comment: I'm not faulting your answer... I'm just trying to find out what we're solving here.  Your answer merely proves the OP's code should have been working all along.

Comment: The user was searching for a working example of his code I thought.... So I decided to write a complete fiddle with his code and not only mark the syntax errors. If you want I provide a better explanation

Comment: Like I said, I don't see anything wrong with your answer.  I just think the OP should have shown more code or explained where he went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There was syntax error

just added colon in password: after maxlength: 10,

your code working fine.now

```
<script>

  $("#Myform").validate({
   rules: {
     password: { 
       required: true,
       minlength: 6,
       maxlength: 10,

     } , 

     cfmPassword: { 

      equalTo: "#password",
      minlength: 6,
      maxlength: 10
    }


  }

});
</script>
```

Comment: yes.. , i tried but not worked. . .

Comment: you can check here http://jsfiddle.net/bqLbu/2/

Comment: yor're welcome @user3599482

Comment: hi , I have small problem , I have reset button for form, for that I just wrote javascript reset() method , it just remove content in text boxes but it keeps all jquery error msgs and valid icons, So how to write reset method to clear all . .

Comment: write this     $('#reset').click(function()
            {
              $('.content').load('');  
            });                                                                                           <input type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" placeholder="reset">